# Temperature increase of a gas in a period of time

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas

Pardon my simple question for you physics geniuses but:

I'm attempting to simulate hot air balloons for a game. I have a gas of known volume, temperature, pressure and density inside a confined space.

This is the formula I'm using to determine the pressure of the gas.  As gas is added to the balloon and the volume increases, the pressure of the gas will equal the external air pressure until a maximum volume is reached at which point, the pressure increases.

$$
\begin{equation}
P =
\begin{cases}
P_\text{ext} &\text{for } V<V_\text{max}\\
nRT/V_\text{max} &\text{for } V\ge V_\text{max},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
simplified into:
$$
P = \max(P_\text{ext},\, nRT/V_\text{max}).
$$

Picture a hot air balloon. When the propane burner above the basket is turned on, the air in the balloon heats up. When it's turned off, the air cools.

**What I need is a simple formula that tells me that if x amount of heat (joules, btu, etc.) is applied to this gas over a period of time (typically 0.02 sec) what the temperature should be.**

Note: While I do know much about this gas, one thing I do not know is the specific heat. I can probably make an educated guess using the information the game provides if it's needed.

There will be a maximum temperature that the gas can reach either through the formula itself by changing the burner's output or I will adjust the formula used for cooling (Newton's law of cooling) to keep the temperature somewhat realistic.  At present i'm looking at 600-700 kelvin for this max temperature (while not realistic this max temperature is based on the gas density and thus the lift the gas produces at that temperature).

I do not need to delve into the finite details of physics or achieve extreme accuracy as this is a game.  Consider this to be an ideal gas situation where the heat is applied uniformly. I simply need to give the end user the 'feel' of flying a hot air balloon by using a real-world physics formula as the base for these calculations.

I hope this is enough information to give you and idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You always want an increase in temperature when the burner is on? Or do you want it to be more realistic that there is a maximum temperature you can obtain from a given burner heat output. It also depends on how much detail you want. Are you considering heat loss to the environment as well?

Comment: There will be a maximum temperature that the gas can achieve.  ATM, I'm looking at 500 kelvn just to give the players room to experiment.

Comment: So you are putting in a set limit independent of any physical reason? Do you always want that to be the limit? You will probably have to simplify things greatly. How physically accurate do you want to be? And will more accuracy even have a huge impact on the game?

Comment: There's no 'physical' reason to set a limit no.  For realistic purposes that limit is considerably higher than what I understand most hot air balloons operate at but this is a physics based game and I want to give the players the ability to go a bit above what's realistic.  A simplified formula will be perfect.  The game engine can handle quite a bit of accuracy but that's not really needed. I just need something that has it's basis in real-world physics and not some formula I create off the top of my head to 'simulate' heating a gas.

Comment: I will have to come up with a formula for heat loss but that will have a lot of numbers that I'd have to 'imagine' so it will likely be more playability based rather than physics based.

Comment: Would you want heating from the burner and heat loss to the environment to be happening at the same time? Or are you just going to apply one scenario depending on whether or not the burner is on? You might want to look into Newton's law of cooling.

Comment: The way it'll work is: Every cycle of the game which is roughly 1/60 sec, the code performs all of the calculations. So from a theoretical standpoint, the laws of physics are frozen in between these cycles.  During that time I'm performing a lot of calculations to determine how much lift is being produced.  In theory, the burners would heat the gas at one stage of those calculations and then a bit later, the heat loss would occur.  Just briefly looked at Newton's law and it will take some study to understand but it looks good. Thanks! Cooling will always occur.

Comment: Newton's cooling worked great. Thanks for that idea. Still need a good solution to heating.

Comment: You can use Newton's cooling for heating too. Just define a temperature of your heat source and if the initial temperature is less than this then the temperature will increase.

Comment: Question edited to hopefully explain better what I need.